# Error in using Fetch API in Vue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I use the following code to read a file using `fetch`:

```
fetch('rest.txt', {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data=> console.log(data));
```

And in the browser console I get the following response instead of the text of the file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./static/favicon.ico"/>
    <title>TRAINSET</title>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-91042619-2"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-91042619-2');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
<style>
html, body {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
</style>
```

I tried the same thing yesterday and it worked fine but today it doesn't.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: What happens if you try to retrieve the file directly by typing the URL into the browser's address bar?

Comment: I'm guessing "URL scheme "file" is not supported." you need to run the site on a web server, you cannot just open the file in a browser.

Comment: But i was able to read just two days back and I'm not able to today. Hows that possible

Comment: can you add "catch()" and show whats the error.

Comment: There are no errors . I want context of file in the console but instead I'm getting above response.

Comment: Try removing `{mode: 'no-cors'}`

Comment: I tried removing {mode: 'no-cors'} but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add
var customData = require('./rest.txt');
in the starting.
It solved the problem for me.
Without this, fetch will not run if it's running on server.
Without server running, fetch will work without this.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I've copied directly that code and run with http-server

```
  fetch('/rest.txt', {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data=> console.log(data));
```

and it works

Can you show all the context where that code is used?

Comment: Do you get the text of file as output?

Comment: Is the problem with npm version?

Comment: 1.yes 2.I don't use npm I just use that chunk of code